# How to draw a line from the middle of the page to the right side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

How to draw a line (using css, html or js) from the middle of the page to the right side?

This should work on a different screen resolutions.

The example provided in the picture.[image: example]

Comment: But the example lines don't start in the middle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="line"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.line {
    width: 75%;
    height: 1px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    background: red;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/N2n3c/)

Answer (score 2):

Using a horizontal rule in css.

```
hr {
 color: white;
 background: blue; 
 width: 75%; 
 height: 5px;
 margin-left:25%;
}

<body>
<hr />
<hr/>
</body>
```

Please see jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yvytty/jJRAt/

Comment: That's exactly the same answer. :) As a note: Use the `<hr>`-tag only if it has a semantic meaning as the specs define: "*The hr element represents a paragraph-level thematic break.*" You can read more about it here: "[The small & hr elements](http://html5doctor.com/small-hr-element/)".

Comment: even thought I have to say that the code from yvytty is better then yours insertusernamehere. you can paste the <hr /> everywhere you want to create easy and always the same line length

Comment: @yvytty Hey, this happens very often. That's why I mentioned it with a smiley and not in any way to offend you. :)

Comment: @RyandeVries It deppends on the use case. Please accept yvytty's answer, if it fits your situation better. :)

Comment: @yvytty It's not a race. So always take your time and don't go for the "fastest gun in the west" thingy. Quality and to fit the OP's needs is what matters here.

Comment: Yeah that will happen a lot. But if it's still a good question, go for it. As you said yourself, it may help somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**html:**

```
<div id="lineID" class="line"></div>
```

**css:**

```
 .line{  
    background:red;    
    height: 1px;
margin-left:50%;
        }
```

**javascript for more dynamic control**:

```
//you can also put all the css in here

    var scr=screen.width/2
    var myLine = document.getElementById('lineID');
    myLine.style.cssText= "width:"+scr+"px";
```

[fiddle of course!](http://jsfiddle.net/bBPcU/1/)

Answer (score 1):

To my mind the best way to get a line from the middle to the right which scales correctly and is pure CSS is the following:

HTML

```
<div class="lineblock"></div>
```

CSS

```
  .lineblock{
    width: 50%; /*width can vary yours looks to be ~75% */
    height: 20px; /* Random thickness I chose to make sure I saw it on the page */
    float: right; /* Always forces to the right-hand side of the parent (so make sure
                     you're in the top level of the page or have no 'container' div
                     surrounding your line)*/
    background: magenta; /*shows on anything*/
}
```

This method is both - a) Going to scale to all device screen sizes and be 50% of the viewport, and, b) be dumb enough to be IE 8 + safe (probably more but I only test to 8 it is used by about 10-12% of people internationally* and below that is almost nobody these days).

Sources:
HTML - Simple div
CSS - Experimentation
Browser Stats - Stat Counter's browser version usage for [this month past.](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201204-201304-bar)

- Correct at time of writing.